# I have an error (The Schematic workflow failed) in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular6-json-schema-form

I installed angular 7 in my windows 10 and the version of my configurations are :

```
Node : v11.8.0
npm : 6.7.0

Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 11.8.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
```

...

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.3
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.3
@angular/cli                 7.2.3
@angular/fire                5.1.0
@schematics/angular          7.2.3
@schematics/update           0.12.3
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.2
```

when i create a new project in angular it's show  error  (**The Schematic workflow failed**)in the photo below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OrMT.jpg)

How can i solve this problem

Comment: [Try this Answer Link for resolving this issue][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455400/10538842

Answer (score 3):

1. Uninstall your current Global Angular cli npm uninstall -g
   @angular/cli
2. Run npm cache verify
3. Re-Install Angular CLI npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
4. Create your new project using ng new command

Comment: I have tried the same solution but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try the of this post. But in case of mine these steps did not help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441929/1115166

If Issue still remains. I would suggest delete everything from the

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

folder.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall your current Global Angular using `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Run `npm cache verify`

Re-Install Angular CLI `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Then, before you try to re-create your project using `ng new {projectname}` make sure you delete the previously-created one, otherwise, you will get the same error. You can navigate to `c/users/{yourusername}` to see all the projects that were previously created unsuccessfully.