# the schematic workflow failed

Tags: angular, nativescript

Whenever I tried using
`ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics --name=my-app --shared`
OR
Any of the other command line commands to generate a project in which I can
develop PWA app (Web + Mobile) it also ends with error as follows -
the schematic workflow failed.
I have installed latest versions of
NPM
Angular cli
Nativescript cli
nativescript/schematics
I am doing this on windows 8
Anybody know what the problem is?

Have searched online but have failed to get a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check Node and Npm versions using the below command.

   ```
   node -v 

   npm -v
   ```
2. if npm version >= 7.As per online info, the Angular team recommends using npm 6 for now.

   ```
   npm install -g npm@6
   ```
3. clean npm cache

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
4. install latest NG CLI

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try downgrading you angular version to 8/9 schematics may work there (especially Angular 8)

to do so,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli8
```