# Why ng new newApp producing unable to resolve dependency tree error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web, npm

I am trying to create a new angular app using the command
 `ng new app-name`.. But after running the command, it is showing the following in the command line.

```
Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-module@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/vazha/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vazha/.npm/_logs/2021-05-07T05_12_55_121Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Try this Answer Link for resolving this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455400/10538842

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This error is caused by an npm 7 issue. The Angular team recommends to use npm 6 for now.

Run `npm install -g npm@6` to ensure that you are using that version.

An alternative can be to run `ng new` with the `--skipInstall` flag, and then install the dependencies with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Thank you Soooooo much.. I was stuck here.

Comment: Thank you! I was already wondering why it suddenly stopped working...

Comment: This command throws an error for me. So I open cmd on Windows 10 with the Administrator rights (as Administrator) and then npm install -g npm@6. It works! Thank you.

Comment: The frustration I am about to voice really isn't directed at this answer. But I have run across several SO questions of this nature and answers that say "the angular team recommends to use npm 6 at this time". It would be nice to have a link to where the angular team is saying that, so that folks can look at it and see if that is still the current state of things.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-773569798 is the thread I was reading through yesterday.  We're not seeing it because they stopped recommending that around February of this year. From what I can tell.

Answer (score 9):

First create the project as usual:

```
ng new <project>
```

Then go to the project directory and change version of jasmine-core in
package.json to "^3.7.1". Then start install again:

```
npm install
```

This is a temporary solution but it works

Comment: Yeah thank you, but will there be other errors that may rise as we are using `--force` here

Answer (score 2):

Angular no longer recommends npm 6 (see [npm install fails with NPM 7](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19957#issuecomment-773569798) for more information), so the current answer is a little different.

In this particular case you can try creating a new application and have the Angular CLI skip the `npm install` step. With Angular 12.x, the command is `ng new your-project-name --skip-install`. This will still setup Git, and just require a `npm install`.

Before doing so, however, you'll want to determine what the issue is and fix the package.json.

This particular dependency seems to be recurring issue, as it started breaking again. See [npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21326).

For individuals coming in early July 2021, update package.json so that `"jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",` is listed in the package.json, and then run `npm install` in the root of the project directory. This should leave you ready to go, which you should be able to confirm with a `ng serve --open`.

The full steps:

1. `ng new your-project-name --skip-install`
2. `cd your-project-name`
3. Open package.json in the editor of your choice.
4. Edit the package.json to fix the dependency issue.
5. `npm install`
6. Fix any issues that may arise, if needed.
7. `ng serve --open` to verify the project is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still experiencing this after trying all of the above options, just downgrade npm version from 7 to 6: npm install -g npm@6